# launch one jasmine test with grunt and karma?

Tags: unit-testing, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a big web project with many javascript Jasmine unit tests.
In that web project, i use grunt, karma and jasmine.

Is there any way to launch only one test javascript with grunt with a command line ?

Launching all tests is long, so how to do that without modify my gruntfile.js or my karma-unit.conf.js ??

I tried the following command, but it is more a hack than a real solution :

```
karma run -- --grep=filteredtestexpr
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the best way to specify which test to run from the command line. But it seems like your problem can be solved with the following two pointers:

- Change the name of a test from `it` to `iit` and karma will run only that test (actually all `iit` tests).
- Change `describe` to `ddescribe` to run the entire describe block.

Also, use `xit` and `xdescribe` to explicitly exclude tests.